# Set RAILS_ENV in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Please considering following code:

```rb
class MyModel
  validate my_validation unless ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "test" 
end
```

We have a validation that is going to have major effect on HUGE parts of the test-suite. I only want it to be executed in prod, not when running the test suite*... EXCEPT for the actual tests regarding this validation.

So when testing the validation I need to set the `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` to something else then test. I tried this in my `my_model_spec.rb`-file:

```rb
it "tests the validation" do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "development"
  
  # Tests the validation..
  
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
end
```

This sets the variable while in the spec file, BUT where the check is made in `my_model.rb` the `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` still returns "test".

Is there a way to achieve the declaration of `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` in the SPEC-file and have that still set when the model code is executed during the example run?

---

- Yes yes, please believe me we have this under control (... I think :D). It is during a maintenance window.

Comment: If huge parts of your test-suite fail with the validation in place, how can you be sure that it will work in production? It would probably be better to adapt the tests to the new validation rather the other way round.

Comment: It took ~23 minutes 

Comment: Sorry @Stefan, I don't mean to come off as douche but I was keeping time for this comment to appear :D - I do appreciate your concern though and we will carefully consider it. BTW you were totally right in the comment bellow! Thank you again for taking time to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obligatory:

```
validate my_validation unless ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "test"
```

In 99.9% of cases, this is really not a good idea.

Just felt I needed to make that clear, in case future readers see this post and get funny ideas... (It would be much better to update the test suite to remain valid, e.g. by changing the factories.)

> Is there a way to achieve the declaration of `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` in the SPEC-file

Yes - you can stub the value:

```
allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).with('RAILS_ENV').and_return('development')
```

There are also some other approaches you could consider.

For example, why not call the method directly, for the purpose of running this test?

```
record = MyModel.new # or using FactoryBot.build / whatever
record.my_validation
```

Or, you could add a model attribute to forcibly-run the validation:

```
class MyModel
  attr_accessor :run_my_validation
  validate my_validation if ENV["RAILS_ENV"] != "test" || run_my_validation
end

# and in the test:
record = MyModel.new # or using FactoryBot.build / whatever
record.run_my_validation = true
expect(record.valid?).to be_true
```

Yet another approach you could consider, to eliminate rails environment check from the production code, would be to set an [environment-specific configuration value](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration). Which, again, you could stub in the spec:

```
class MyModel
  validate my_validation if Rails.configuration.run_my_model_validation
end

# and in the test:
allow(Rails.configuration).to receive(:run_my_model_validation).and_return(true)
```

Another benefit to the above is that you *could* enable the validation in development mode, without making any code change to the application.

Comment: You should use `validate my_validation, if: -> { ... }` – otherwise the condition will be evaluated only once when loading the class.

Comment: Nice Tom Lord and @Stefan - your answers combined worked!